# Working with XML in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, root

I'am working with an hierarchical xml structure like this:

```
<employee name="AAA" group="1"..../>
    <employee name="BBB" group="1"...>
        <employee name="CCC" group="1".../>
     </employee>  
    <employee name="DDD" group="0"... />
    <employee name="EEE" group="0"... />
</employee>
```

First I need to count all employee nodes (including root node). It must be: 5.
I have tried using xml..employee.length() but it returns 4 (does not include the root node "AAA")
If I tried xml.employee.length() only returns 1

Then, I have to create a XMList with specific search. For example all the nodes with attribute group="1"

The same problem occurs, I use: hitList:XMLList = xml..employee.(@group == "1") and returns the right result but it does not take in count the root node (in this case, it must be included)

How can I do this operations including the root node?

Thanks in advance

Cristian

Comment: The first tag seems to be incorrect. It should not be closed with "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a XML variable is identical to the root XML tag. So if you wright

```
xml..employee.length()
```

it means you analyze all the nodes under the root node. The variable xml is your root node.

To get a correct result you need to add an empty dummy root node in your structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XML id="xml" xmlns="">
        <root>
            <employee name="AAA" group="1">
                <employee name="BBB" group="1">
                    <employee name="CCC" group="1"/>
                </employee>  
                <employee name="DDD" group="0"/>
                <employee name="EEE" group="0"/>
            </employee>
        </root>
    </fx:XML>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void
        {
            var len:int = xml..employee.length(); //gives 5
            var hitList:XMLList = xml..employee.(@group == "1"); //gives 3 nodes

            trace();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, I could fix it following your suggestion.